# Firebase: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error on every device

Tags: google-chrome, firebase

So, when I go into the firebase console I just get a never ending loading screen, and in Google Chrome I get the following error when I control-shift-i: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

I have tried to open the firebase console on Internet explorer and Mozilla as well but to no avail.  I also tried getting in on 4 different devices and none of them worked. At this point I thought it was something wrong with my google account, so I created  a brand new google account and get the same issue.  Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with the WiFi hotspot I was connected to so I just connected to another one